# Error: Unable to open image while ingesting into earth engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am trying to upload and ingest a raster file of TIF format into the earth engine. The data is stored in GCS and I used CLI to make the upload. Upload is complete, but ingestion is interrupted throwing an error:

> Error: Unable to open sample_image.tif

I am using jupyter notebook to implement the code and here is the code to upload data

```py
!earthengine upload image --asset_id=users/ksvsp/sample_image pyramiding_policy=sample gs://cloud-ksvsp-ee/sample_image.tif`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your image is readable by the Google account that starts the Earth Engine ingestion. We sometimes see issues with multilogin, so try logging in an anonymous window to be sure.